# Parsing date in android forcing app to close

Tags: android, parsing, date, format, formatter

I have this code:

```
aktiv_date = dateaktiv.getText().toString();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
try {
     aktiv_dat = formatter.parse(aktiv_date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I give it a number like: 12101989 or something similar, that does not have the format dd.MM.yyyy the program crashes because it says the data from aktiv_date is unparseable at line:

```
 aktiv_dat = formatter.parse(aktiv_date);
```

What could i do to make it not crash?

Comment: The Logcat log says the same thing i said up: javanullpointerexception and then it takes me to that line: aktiv_dat = formatter.parse(aktiv_date);

Comment: @rosualin: No, you said *nothing* about a NullPointerException in your post. It would really help if you'd post the information from the log. I've made a guess based on what you've told us so far, but it really is hard to work with such incomplete information.

Comment: @rosualin show your code about Calenedar programming formate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're catching the `ParseException`, dumping the exception, *and then continuing as if nothing has gone wrong*.

You haven't shown where `aktiv_dat` is declared, but I suspect it's got a value of `null` if the parse fails... hence the `NullPointerException`. Printing a stack trace and then continuing is almost *never* the right way of handling an exception. You should think about how you want your program to behave in the face of invalid data - do you want to use a default date, do you want to abandon just that operation, etc...

Comment: 10x, i'd changed the try catch to call the WS call into try, and if not to make a toast that the format is not correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try edit like this:

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");